# Is it possible to walk stack frames from an Exception?

Tags: java

I want to log the first stack frame which is visible from within my own code. Is it possible to walk a stack trace from a `Throwable` - something similar to `StackWalker.walk(...)`

Comment: If you have instance of `Throwable` it doesn't necessary means it has been throw/caught (are you planing to use it in try/catch block?). There is `java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()` but not sure what exactly you're trying to do. Maybe you can just `throwable.getStackTrace()[1]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most correct way is to pay the penalty and stream the `Throwable.getStackTrace()`...

This will though come with performance issues as the jvm must create all elements in the stack trace (not just the ones you want)...

If paying this performance overhead is not an option, you should "walk the stack" using the `StackWalker` from the java 9 stack walking api... This stack will deviate from the exception stack trace, and this needs to be considered when walking the stack...

Comment: *"This stack will deviate from the exception stack trace"* - some more details (or a link) about how it will deviate would be helpful.

Comment: (I think he is saying that you get the stack frames for the current call context rather than for call context where the exception was instantiated.)

Answer (score 1):

You can stream the StacktraceElements:

```
Arrays.stream(throwable.getStackTrace().forEach(element ->{
    if(element.getClassName().startsWith("your.package"){
        logger.info(element.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: I now you can stream the array, but this will cause performance overhead. The JVM needs to initialise every element in the stack... If you walk the stack, only the elements being walked over is initialised...

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to stream the results of `Throwable.getStackTrace()`

> I know you can stream the array, but this will cause performance overhead.

In fact, it won't.  The overheads of capturing the stack frames and turning them into an array of `StackFrameElement` is incurred when `fillInStackTrace()` is called.  This happens during the instantiation of the `Throwable` (exception) object; i.e. *before* you `throw` it.

Basically, you have *already* taken the performance overhead of creating the array ... before you decide if you want to stream the stack frames or not.

On the flipside, it is possible to instantiate a `Throwable` (via a subclass) with the `writableStackTrace` argument set to `false`.  That inhibits the call to `fillInStackTrace`.  The net result is that no stackframes will be captured ... and there would be nothing to stream.

(And you can't change the mind.  If the stackframes don't get captured when the `Throwable` is instantiated, they will be discarded as the stack is unwound during propagation of the exception.)

Comment: This is also my understanding, but since this contradicts another answer, it would help to include a reference - and to clarify whether this is version-specific or not.

Comment: My source of information is the source code for `java.lang.Throwable`.  It does vary a bit.  The `writableStackTrace` behavior is a relatively recent change.

Comment: However the call to `fillInStackTrace` has been there for as long as I can remember.  (Along with the trick of overriding it ... which was the old way to suppress a stacktrace.)